# Working with spatial data for India when key state truncated due to territory issues?

Tags: data

I am in India, working with  spatial data. The data is downloaded from gadm.org http://gadm.org/ The state of Jammu and Kashmor (the top most state) is truncated (it reflects ground reality where 1/3 of state is with Pakistan and rest with India).

For legal reasons I need to show the whole state (though obviously I have data for 2/3 provinces, How do I go about it. Almost all global maps show the truncated map which I cannot use.

My tools are R and Python /SAS VA

See below for India:

[image]

See below for for GADM image

[image]

How can i work (programming) with static map untruncated image and dynamic geospatial (rest of map)?

I have both data sources so its not a data source problem.

How do I merge the two maps (top of one map with bottom of other)?

Comment: Which is the data format of the first image you posted?

Comment: a .png format since its political